# node.js - turn Hugging Face image response to buffer and send as a discord attachment

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, discord.js, huggingface

I am trying to get a response from huggingface.com's stable diffusion, but the response I get is encrypted and I can't just turn it into a buffer and send it as a discord.js attachment.

Is there any way to fix this?

The response I get: `�,���$eF*dh�F8��4�b��A�,9���tr8ڠ��V#�e�����U�H��Jr�������b�`...

my code:

```js
var data = interaction.options.getString("prompt")

    axios.post(

        "https://api-inference.huggingface.co/models/runwayml/stable-diffusion-v1-5",

        {

            inputs: data,

        },

        { Authorization: "Bearer ive placed my token here",

               Accept: 'application/json',

        'Content-Type': 'application/json',}

    ).then(r => {

      console.log(r.data) // => returns unknown encoded data

      var buffer = Buffer.from(r.data)

      var attach = new AttachmentBuilder(buffer, {name: 'result.png'})

      interaction.reply({files: [attach]}) // => does not work

    });
```

I expected that I would get a JSON response, turn the base64 encoded to buffer, and send it as a discord attachment. But what I got from the response was some encrypted data that I cant work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default response type in axios is `json` so you will need to change it to `arraybuffer`. Also, you should defer the `interaction` and use `editReply` to avoid the interaction to fail.

The following should work:

```js
await interaction.deferReply();

const data = interaction.options.getString('prompt');

try {
  let result = await axios.post(
    'https://api-inference.huggingface.co/models/runwayml/stable-diffusion-v1-5',
    {
      inputs: data,
    },
    {
      Authorization: 'YOUR_TOKEN_IF_NEEDED',
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    },
  );
  const buffer = Buffer.from(result.data);
  const attach = new AttachmentBuilder(buffer, { name: 'result.jpeg' });

  await interaction.editReply({ files: [attach] });
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
  interaction.editReply('There was an error. Try again later!');
}
```

[image]